# prevent tableview from scrolling while scrolling inside a tableviewcell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

i've got a tableview. inside this, i have a tableviewcell with a horizontal scrollview inside it.

it works fine, but if i start scrolling horizontal inside a tableviewcell and move a bit up or down, the horizontal scrolling stops and the tableview gets scrolled.

is there a way to prevent the tableview from scrolling while scrolling horizontal inside a tableviewcell?

thanks for all help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO`

If that doesn't work you may have to do more complicated handling of touch events by subclassing UIScrollView. (Look at `touchesBegan:event:, touchesMoved:event:, touchesEnded:event:, touchesCancelled:event:`)

Comment: looks like `scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO` is working :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you should not put the `UIScrollView` inside an `UITableView`. you could show the content of your cell vertically Or show on the details view

`UITableView`  is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.

**Form Apple Documentation.**

> Important: You should not embed
>   UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so,
>   unexpected behavior can result because
>   touch events for the two objects can
>   be mixed up and wrongly handled.

[More](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIScrollView)

Comment: `not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects` but i do it the other way round. i embed a uiscrollview inside a uitableview, or better, inside a tableviewcell

Comment: @choise  : The reason of mentioning "UIWebView or UITableView"  only because they are inherited from UIScrollView, So if your have one UIScrollView (UITableViewCell's UIScrollView ) inside other UIScrollView  (UITableView) you will get unexpected behavior during scrolling as explained in answer.

Comment: and what would you say about that: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html